# Firefox extensions "restricted" from running on some sites

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I run a lot of extensions, and I happened to notice that none seemed to work with [Mozilla Addons](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/).
I checked each extension, and some specifically whitelisted this site, but I changed that.
I also checked with `about:preferences`, and removed the value of `extensions.webextensions.restrictedDomains`. This seemed to have an effect on some sites mentioned by this string, like [Firefox Accounts](https://accounts.firefox.com). But the Mozilla addons site seems to be unaffected.

My questions are:
Are there other whitelists I have missed that disable extensions from running?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that browser extensions are prohibited from running on certain pages to protect the user's security and privacy. Bypassing this restriction will be done at your own risk.

---

Workaround #1: From [this page](https://github.com/gorhill/uMatrix/wiki/Privileged-Pages) on gorhill's uMatrix wiki, empty out the value of `extensions.webextensions.restrictedDomains` and set `privacy.resistFingerprinting.block_mozAddonManager` to `true`. Restart the browser if necessary.

Workaround #2. From [bug 1445663](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1445663#c3), navigate to https://addons.mozilla.org. (with the trailing dot) to allow extensions to run on AMO.

Comment: I did not have the `privacy.resistFingerprinting.block_mozAddonManager` entry in my `about:config`, but adding it worked.
Workaround #2 worked as well.